# How to use custom function in posts and pages templates

Tags: theme-development

I want to add a custom function to get related posts into my wp theme.

I have added this function code to my theme functions.php file but it will not work:

```
  function my_related_artickes()
  {
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID ); 
    $ids = array();
    foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        $ids[] = $cat;
    }
    return $ids;
  }
```

I'm calling the function in this way:

```
<?php     
    $ids = my_related_articles();
    var_dump($ids);
    $related = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post', 'category__in' => $ids, 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) ); 
    if( $related->have_posts() ): while( $related->have_posts() ): $related->the_post(); 
?>    
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 mt-3 mb-3 d-none d-md-block">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100 related-img mb-3" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
            <a class="h5 text-decoration-none" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: You have a typo. my_related_articles() and my_related_artickes(). Lets start there :)

Comment: fixed, but the problem still persist.

Comment: The code who call the function is inside a template part, but I don't think is this the problem. `single-related-loop.php` is a proper name for the file and don't collide with wordpress.

Comment: Du you get the correct categories from the var_dump?

Comment: nope. It output nothing. the function isn't fired I think!

Comment: You might have to echo the_title and the_permalink. What are your results now? Nothing? Try to print_r($related) and see what you have.

Comment: The problem is different, the query works if the function is on the same file. Will not load anything if I have the function code in `functions.php`. The query will not work, needs to get the ids of the desired category as you can see in the code.

Comment: I can't see any problem with having all the code on in the same file if only using these ids here.

Comment: found the problem. It was a typo inside the code in a `get_template_part()` function :') ! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

One problem (there may be more ;-) is that `$post->ID` is probably out of scope when you call it from the page template.

You could change the way the function works to take the post ID as a parameter, like this:

```
function my_related_artickes($postID)
{
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $postID ); 
    $ids = array();
    foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        $ids[] = $cat;
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
$ids = my_related_articles($post->ID);
```

Obviously when you call it make sure that you give it a good post ID.

Comment: This make sense.